# Issue getting wkhtmltoimage working on Amazon Linux / Ruby on Rails

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, yum, amazon-linux

It works fine on my development environment (osx), but I can't get it to work on the server.

in my gemfile

```
gem 'imgkit'
gem 'wkhtmltoimage-binary'
```

When I run:

```
kit = IMGKit.new(html, quality: 100)
img_binary = kit.to_img
```

I get this error

```
IMGKit::CommandFailedError: Command failed: 
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/wkhtmltoimage --height 0 --quality 100 --format jpg - -: 
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/wkhtmltoimage-binary-0.12.5/libexec/wkhtmltoimage-amd64: 
error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've searched online and tried installing some more packages, but no success. Anyone able to help? Thanks.

Comment: Any chance you ever found a resolution to this?  I'm seeing the exact same behavior when ran on a CircleCI instance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `'wkhtmltoimage-binary', '~> 0.11.0.1.1'` in the Gemfile fixed the issue for me. Found the solution [here](https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit/issues/79).